# Help writing ScheduleBatch Apex class

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch

I have to write a Schedulebatch apex class on two objects

1. Case
2. Ticket__C

Ticket__c has a lookup to case and a case can have many ticket records but a ticket can only be associated to one case record

The Batch Apex class should run every morning at 2:00am and look at two fields(Status) in both the objects. Batch Apex shouls look at all the Cases and all the Tickets associated to the cases.

```
Case       -    Status (Field)
Ticket__c  -    GLOBAL_Ticket_Status__c (Field)
```

For example : if a case is associated with 3 Ticket_*c records and the status of case is open, but status on 2 ticket*_c records are closed and not the third record. Do not do anything.

If status of all the Ticket_*c records are set to closed for a particular Case record but the Case record status itself is still open, Close the case after 7 days of Ticket*_c records status closed. (This is because if business want to add a ticket to that particular case they can just because the case status is not closed).

Any help in either how to initialize the objects and its fields or if anyone can write or guide me to write code will be much appreciated

thank you

---

Automatically close the Case by Updating the Case(Object) Status(Picklist field) to closed if the Ticket__c($Object) records associated to that particular case is Closed (GLOBAL_Ticket_Status__c='Closed')

The requirement is to write a batch apex class on Case($OBJECT) and Ticket__c($OBJECT) which runs at 2:00am every morning.

1. Looks at all the case records and all the ticket_*C records which are associated to that case [ticket*_c has a lookup to Case]
2. Then looks at Ticket__C status field (GLOBAL_Ticket_Status__c) related to that particular Case ID , if the status is anything other than closed do not do anything
3. If the Ticket__C status field (GLOBAL_Ticket_Status_*c) related to that particular Case ID is closed and was closed since the past 7 days then close the Case  [Have to lookat Last Modified Date on Ticket*_c Record]

I hope i made myself clear

Thankyou

---

```
Trigger Ticket on Ticket__c (after insert, after update) {
        Set<Id> closedTicketIds = new Set<Id>();
            for (Ticket__c ticket: Trigger.new) {
             if (ticket.GLOBAL_Ticket_Status__c == 'closed') {
             closedTicketIds.add(ticket.id);
        }
    }
    List<Ticket__c> ticketForClosing= [SELECT Id, GLOBAL_Goal__c FROM Ticket__c
                                  WHERE Id IN: closedTicketIds];

        set<Id> caseIDs = new set<Id>();
            for(Ticket__c t : ticketForClosing){
            caseIDs.add(t.GLOBAL_Goal__c);
    }
        List<Case> casesToUpdate = new List<Case>();
            for (Case c : [Select Id, Status From Case Where Id In : caseIDs]) {
            c.Status = 'closed';
            casesToUpdate.add(c);
    }
    update casesToUpdate;
}
```

But the problem is, the trigger does not look at all the Ticket_*C records associated to a Case. It only Looks at Status Closed records and updates Case status to closed despite some of the status on ticket*_c is still open or on hold

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Can you elaborate on what problem you're facing? Have you reviewed the documentation and guides provided by Salesforce? As it stands, this question is very broad and likely to be closed unless you can narrow the scope to something specific.

Comment: I am not so sure that you should use batch for this job....
How many records you have to process? Because mayby time workflow + trigger could be good solution?

Comment: I work for a public sector and do not have access to live data. I did write a trigger and was told that Batch apex was the best solution

Comment: I have written the trigger, please see the answer

Comment: Automatically close the Case by Updating the Case(Object) Status(Picklist field) to closed if the Ticket__c($Object) records associated to that particular case is Closed (GLOBAL_Ticket_Status__c='Closed')

The requirement is to write a batch apex class on Case($OBJECT) and Ticket__c($OBJECT) which runs at 2:00am every morning.

Looks at all the case records and all the ticket_C records which are associated to that case [ticket_c has a lookup to Case]

Comment: Then looks at Ticket__C status field (GLOBAL_Ticket_Status__c) related to that particular Case ID , if the status is anything other than closed do not do anything

If the Ticket__C status field (GLOBAL_Ticket_Status_c) related to that particular Case ID is closed and was closed since the past 7 days then close the Case [Have to lookat Last Modified Date on Ticket_c Record]

I hope i made myself clear

Thankyou